# How to alias a built-in type in C#?

Tags: c#, alias

So in C++, I'm used to being able to do:

```
typedef int PeerId;
```

This allows me to make a type more self-documenting, but additionally also allows me to make PeerId represent a different type at any time without changing all of the code. I could even turn PeerId into a class if I wanted. This kind of extensibility is what I want to have in C#, however I am having trouble figuring out how to create an alias for 'int' in C#.

I think I can use the using statement, but it only has scope in the current file I believe, so that won't work (The alias needs to be accessible between multiple files without being redefined). I also can't derive a class from built-in types (but normally this is what I would do to alias ref-types, such as List or Dictionary). I'm not sure what I can do. Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you derive from built-in types?

Comment: I'm just curious?  What would be a situation or reason someone would want to do this?  Sorry if this sounds weird, I'm just ignorant on why you would not want to use int.  It sounds like it would be confusing for another developer to read your code.

Comment: Agree, interested to read this, but it must be bad practise

Comment: It's **not** bad practice. It's used when [a] the datatype may change [b] you want to hide the implementation details (because they may change).

Comment: @egrunin - if the data type might change, you'd want to check/rewrite everywhere that uses the code, and so with one minor change you'd potentially introduce bugs or break that code.  Sounds like Generics might work well for this kind of thing instead? (not to mention, it only applies for one code file, right? so if you have well-structured multi-class code, you'd need to add it in every file, which seems very redundant). I might be wrong of course..

Comment: @arootbeer: value types are by definition sealed.

Comment: Looking for guidance here, I believe that aliasing a built-in type is useful for strong type checking. For example, suppose I have a program that deals with milliseconds as an int field and seconds as another int field. Creating typedefs for milliseconds and seconds is one way to ensure that no comparisons or assignments happen between the two "types" without conversion. What is the C#-centric way to handle those situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since C# 10 you can use **global using**:

```
global using PeerId = System.Int32;
```

It works for all files.

It should appear before all using directives without the global modifier.

See [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive).

Comment: I agree, this is the more ideal answer as of version 10. I have changed the marked answer to this one.

Answer (score 26):

You need to use the full type name like this:

```
using DWORD = System.Int32;
```

Comment: This solution doesn't handle this part of his question: 'I think I can use the using statement, but it only has scope in the current file I believe, so that won't work (The alias needs to be accessible between multiple files without being redefined)'

Answer (score 15):

You could (ab)use implicit conversions:

```
struct PeerId
{
    private int peer;

    public static implicit operator PeerId(int i)
    {
        return new PeerId {peer=i};
    }

    public static implicit operator int(PeerId p)
    {
        return p.peer;
    }
}
```

This takes the same space as an int, and you can do:

```
PeerId p = 3;
int i = p;
```

But I agree you probably don't need this.

Comment: I do this sometimes for slightly more complex value types but I wouldn't do this just to have a name.

Comment: You could also make turning an int into a PeerId an explicit cast. It would provide greater value in certain scenarios by forcing an integrator to consciously cast to the wrapping type. This would be especially useful for things such as functions that take physical units as parameters (operate on feet vs. meters, for instance), preventing certain kinds of trivial mistakes.

Answer (score 15):

**Summary**

Here's the short answer:

- Typedefs are actually a variable used by compile-time code generators.
- C# is being designed to avoid adding code generation language constructs.

Therefore, the concept of typedefs doesn't fit in well with the C# language.

**Long Answer**

In C++, it makes more sense: C++ started off as a precompiler that spit out C code, which was then compiled. This "code generator" beginning still has effects in modern C++ features (i.e., templates are essentially a Turing-complete language for generating classes and functions at compile time). In this context, a typedef makes sense because it's a way to get the "result" of a compile-time type factory or "algorithm" that "returns" a type.

In this strange meta-language (which few outside of Boost have mastered), a typedef is actually a variable.

What you're describing is less complex, but you're still trying to use the typedef as a variable. In this case, it's used as an input variable. So when other code uses the typedef, it's really not using that type directly. Rather, it's acting as a compile-time code generator, building classes and methods based on typedef'ed input variables. Even if you ignore C++ templates and just look at C typedefs, the effect is the same.

**C++ and Generative Programming**

C++ was designed to be a multi-paradign language (OO and procedural, but not functional until Boost came out). Interestingly enough, templates have evolved an unexpected paradign: generative programming. (Generative programming was around before C++, but C++ made it popular). Generative programs are actually meta-programs that - when compiled - generate the needed classes and methods, which are in turn compiled into executables.

**C# and Generative Programming**

Our tools are slowly evolving in the same direction. Of course, reflection emit can be used for "manual" generative programming, but it is quite painful. The way LINQ providers use expression trees is very generative in nature. T4 templates get really close but still fall short. The "compiler as a service" which will hopefully be part of C# vNext appears most promising of all, if it could be combined with some kind of type variable (such as a typedef).

This one piece of the puzzle is [still missing](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/04/t4-almost-complete.html): generative programs need some sort of automatic trigger mechanism (in C++, this is handled by *implicit template instantiation*).

However, it is explicitly *not* a goal of C# to have any kind of "code generator" in the C# language like C++ templates (probably for the sake of understandability; very few C++ programmers understand C++ templates). This will probably be a niche satisfied by T4 rather than C#.

**Conclusion (repeating the Summary)**

All of the above is to say this:

- Typedefs are a variable used by code generators.
- C# is being designed to avoid adding code generation language constructs.

Therefore, the concept of typedefs doesn't fit in well with the C# language.

Comment: Extremely informative response, however it doesn't entail any information I didn't already know, nor does it actually answer my initial question. I was simply mentioning typedefs to give everyone an example of what I'm thinking/expecting. Aliases don't necessarily need to be compile time and can take many forms, such as derivation. If I could do this: "public class PeerId : int {}", that would suffice and solve my problem perfectly.

Comment: haha, [C# Source Generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) go brrr

Answer (score 8):

I also sometimes feel I need (integer) typedefs for similar purposes to the OP.

If you do not mind the casts being explicit (I actually want them to be) you can do this:

`enum PeerId : int {};`

Will also work for `byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, long,` or `ulong` (obviously).

Not exactly the intended usage of `enum`, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Redefining fundamental types just for the sake of changing the name is C++ think and does not sit well with the more pure Object Orientated C#. Whenever you get the urge to shoehorn a concept from one language into another, you must stop and think whether or not it makes sense and try to stay native to the platform.

The requirement of being able to change the underlying type easily can be satisfied by defining your own value type. Coupled with implicit conversion operators and arithmetic operators, you have the power to define very powerful types. If you are worried about performance for adding layers on top of simple types, don't. 99% chance that it won't, and the 1% chance is that in case it does, it will not the be "low hanging fruit" of performance optimization.