# Shorter way to create a dictionary as a parameter without full type declaration

Tags: c#, generics, parameter-passing

For the call to `Test2()` below, is there anyway to make it shorter to omit the explicit typing?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(("a", (1, "b")));
        Test2(new Dictionary<string, (int, string)>()
                { {"a", (1, "b") } });
    }

    static void Test((string, (int, string)) data)
    {
    }
    static void Test2(Dictionary<string, (int, string)> data)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to alias a built-in type in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259267/how-to-alias-a-built-in-type-in-c)

Comment: Use `using` to establish an alias name for your Dictionary<...,...> type as shown in one of the answers in the duplicate question. (btw, you cannot just specify Dictionary<...,...> when declaring an alias name, but you would have to specify the full name of the Dictionary type including its namespace, i.e., `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<...,...>`)

Comment: I think my question is a little different from type aliasing. Ideally, I wanted to omit the type part because it can be inferred like the case of the call to `Test()`. That is, I expected something like `Test2({ {"a", (1, "b") } });`. Don't other languages provide this, like Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, the construct you defined can can fit many types, so it cannot be inferred to mean Dictionary.

Below, I use the params keyword to accept an array of the tuple type you specified and then create a dictionary from it to call the method that expects a Dictionary.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(("a", (1, "b")));
        TestWrap(
            ("a", (1, "b")), 
            ("b", (3, "c"))
            );
    }

    private static void Test((string, (int, string)) data)
    {
    }

    private static void TestWrap(params (string, (int, string))[] data)
    {
        Test2(data.ToDictionary(v => v.Item1, v => v.Item2));
    }

    private static void Test2(Dictionary<string, (int, string)> data)
    {
    }
```

Comment: I agree that it can be other than a `Dictionary`, but the signature of `Test2()` is requiring a `Dictionary`, so I thought if the compiler is intelligent, it could convert it to a `Dictionary`.